# Reseting/clearing antd RangePicker (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, antd

I have a component like this one, i'm trying to make it clear after user selects a date. By default after the user selects a date, its just stay with the selected date and the user needs to manually reset it.

Default behavior:

[image: bad]

Desired behavior:

[image: the RangePicker clears itself (made it with gif editor)]

> ```
> import { DatePicker } from 'antd';
> import moment from 'moment';
>
> const { RangePicker } = DatePicker;
>
> function onChange(dates, dateStrings) {
>   console.log('From: ', dates[0], ', to: ', dates[1]);
>   console.log('From: ', dateStrings[0], ', to: ', dateStrings[1]);
> }
>
> ReactDOM.render(
>   <>
>     <RangePicker
>       ranges={{
>         Today: [moment(), moment()],
>         'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
>       }}
>       onChange={onChange}
>     />
>     <br />
>     <RangePicker
>       ranges={{
>         Today: [moment(), moment()],
>         'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
>       }}
>       showTime
>       format="YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss"
>       onChange={onChange}
>     />
>   </>,
>   mountNode,
> );
> ```

So i tried using the "value" from the antd API, setting the value with state and erasing it with SetState every time the user selects a date (OnChange()) - didn't work.
Also tried to find the clear button function inside antd RangePicker.js - but found it too complicated for me ): .

anyone knows how to solve it?
thank you in advance (: .

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to solve it would be `remounting` the component.

For example, let's say we have a variable `someValue` which holds some value inside it and we assign the value to the `key` of the react component.

`<RangePicker key={someValue} ... />`

On your second date change, just set the `key` to some other value. With this change in value, React will detect a new key and will remount the component leading to all of its previously-stored local states being cleared out.

**EDIT 1**

I noticed you have two date pickers, in that case you need two variables for both of these rangepickers. For example something like:

```
let key1 = 0;
let key2 = 0;
....
<RangePicker key={key1} ../>
<RangePicker key={key2} .. onChange={() => {
   // all the change related to onchange
   //set new values for key1 and key2 
   setKey2(key1++); setKey2(key2++);
}}/>
```

P.S: You remount the component at the last of all your changes, because otherwise it'll try to dispatch an update on an unmounted component.

Comment: for some reason it's not working, maybe because my RangePicker is inside a antd Drawer component?

Answer (score 0):

```
const [dateRange,setDateRange] = useState([])

<RangePicker
name="dateRange"
value={dateRange}
onChange={...whatever you want to do on date Change}
/>

dont update statte on changing dates, in this way, your onChange will also work  and date picker will be cleared.
if you want to store dates in state, don't store moment object, just extract dates from event and store it,
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**You can do it this way**

```
const [dateRange, setDateRange] = useState(['', '']);

const rangeChange = (value, dateString) => {
    console.log(value, dateString);
    setDateRange(dateString);
};

<RangePicker 
  format={['DD/MM/YYYY', 'DD/MM/YY']}
  onChange={(value, dateString) => rangeChange(value, dateString)} 
  defaultValue={dateRange} 
/>
```

[image]